# how to filter out duplicate buy or sell signal in pinescript?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

help me filter out two same signal.

That means I only want buy signal if the previous signal was sell  and vice-versa.

problem :
can't get rid of two same signal

[image]

code:

z1 and z2 are 2 simple moving averages of different period ..

```
     L_buy =  ( (z1 > z2)  and  crossover(rsi,50)  ) or ( crossover(z1,z2)  and rsi > 50 ) 
     L_sell = ( (z1< z2)   and  crossunder(rsi,50) ) or ( crossunder(z1,z2) and rsi < 50 )
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid duplicate signals we will create a switch that will turn off/on after every signal.

```
// S_ = switch
// F_ = final
// Defines Variables for Avoiding Duplicate Signals (Kind of switch)
var S_sell = false
var S_buy = false

// Defines Trade Signals
F_buySignal = not S_sell and bxx
F_sellSignal = not S_buy and sxx

// turning switches off/on after signal is generated 
if F_buySignal
    S_sell := true
    S_buy := false

if F_sellSignal
    S_sell := false
    S_buy := true

plotshape(F_buySignal , color=green , style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar , size=size.small)
plotshape(F_sellSignal , color=red , style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar , size=size.small)
```